# How to specify dict_values in type hints?

Tags: python, type-hinting

My function recives the values from a dictionary. The following MWE should give an impression:

```
def f(x):
    print([y for y in x])

f({'a': 0, 'b': 1}.values()) #prints [0, 1]
```

The type of `x` is not `dict` nor `list` but `dict_values`. However `def f(x: dict_values):` gives the `NameError: name 'dict_values' is not defined`.

So, how to specify dict_values in type hints?

Comment: How is this related to pandas and why does your function specifically need dict_values rather than any arbitrary iterable?

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for your edit - it is not related to pandas, sorry for the wrong tags.

Comment: @Aran-Fey your second question: I'm looking for type hints for dict_values, since the function gets dict_values, and I dont want change the status quo of the function in a way it strictly requires a list etc. I just want to have proper typehints for the status quo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do type hinting with ValuesView:

```
from typing import ValuesView

print(isinstance(dict(a=3).values(), ValuesView))

def f(x: ValuesView):
    print([y for y in x])
```

Comment: Looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html, ValuesView seems to be _the most specific_ class, or am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean with most specific class?

Comment: I mean that `Collection` would work for both, dict_values and lists, but `ValueView` only works for dict_values. So `ValueView` is a more specific class than `Collection`. Now I wondered if it is _the most specific_ class.

Comment: Ah, like that. It seems to me that the other base classes do not inherit from ValuesView so this should be the most specific in collections.abc. This is also used in OrderedDict that I know of but I'm not sure that is a problem?

Comment: This is in the `typing` module nowadays

Comment: thanks, changed it in the answer. Makes more sense to use the typing module

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with trying to use dict_values as a type hint. I didn't want to have to rap it in a tuple or list to give the function a return type. `collections.abc.Iterable` work as a return type.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

def f(x: dict[str, int]) -> Iterable[int]:
    return x.values()

f({'a': 0, 'b': 1})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**